How do I wrap the words by a whitespace in the table header with CSS?
I have a Mat-Table in Angular. The below is the header HTML code.
<ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columns; let j=index">
     <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-header">
        <div *ngFor="let option of options">
            <div class="table-header-title">{{option.title}}</div>
       </div>
     </mat-header-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- ...rest of the code -->

The titles of the header columns are from my backend API ({{option.title}}). Each title usually contains two strings, such as "Some event0"; "some events1-5"; "some events50-500" etc. When I resize the window, the text is wrapped to two lines. What I want is that when it is wrapped to two lines, it should keep the words intact.
For example, if the text "some events50-500" is wrapped to two rows when the window's width is reduced, then the first row should be "some" and the second row should be "events50-500".
But now the first row is showing "Some events5" and the second row is "0-500". Or it shows  "some events" in the first row and "50-500" in the second row.
I want pure CSS to split the text by the whitespace and wrap the words accordingly. I don't want to rewrite my columns array for the table header.


I want pure CSS...

Sorry. That doesn't exist. There's an open issue for standardizing a solution in CSS to handle this situation, but it's just not implemented yet.

I don't want to rewrite my columns array for the table header.

Your best bet for now is likely to replace hyphens with non-breaking hyphens. That would look something like this:
<div>Some event0</div>
<div>some events1&#8209;5</div>
<div>some events50&#8209;500</div>

Now, it's obvious you're building this HTML dynamically using Angular, so I'd suggest one of the following approaches in your component:

Template:
<div [innerHTML]="getTitleFromOption(option)"></div>

Class method:
getTitleFromOption(option: { title: string }): string {
  return option.title.replace(/-/g, '&#8209;');
}


Template:
<div class="table-header-title">{{ getTitleFromOption(option) }}</div>

Class method:
getTitleFromOption(option: { title: string }): string {
  return option.title.replace(/-/g, '‑');
}




But I think that it is not a hyphen issue.  The text is wrapped in any possible position. For example, if the text is "some events123456". There is not a hyphen at all. The first row could be "some events1" and the second row could be "23456".

@Bigeyes All I can do is guess then, since you don't have a reproducible example. Is word-break: break-all; or something similar applied? I'm pretty sure that causes the described behavior. If so, you could override with word-break: normal; (you'd likely need this hyphen fix after that point still)

<div>{{ option.title.replace(/-/g, '‑') }}</div> is not working. Did you miss something in the replace part?

I meant the code didn't know what is g. It asked me to created the field 'g' in Angular. The first way<div [innerHTML]="option.title.replace(/-/g, '&#8209;')"></div> is also not working

Ah, you might just need a function or a pipe to run that code outside of the template then. Angular's templating system doesn't support all of TS/JS syntax. I can update the answer if that helps you

I extracted the title to a method. It is still not working. Perhaps it is Angular material issue. I used mat-header-cell.

I updated the answer with the method fix. To be clear, I think you have two problems on your hands. There's the hyphen problem (which should be fixed in the answer - I tested it) and another problem probably centered around the specific CSS used in your project which I don't have access to. I gave you hints to check your CSS but I don't know what you have going on and "it is still not working" is too ambiguous for me to help with.

Thanks for your input. Your first method converts the hyphen to strangle symbols in different columns. Sometimes it is a white square (U+25A1) and sometimes it is a question mark around a black diamond. Your second method has nothing changed on the UI. Unless I set the replaced value as a different delimiter, such as ~ rather than -, it looks like it will achieve the goal.
